# How to add a spinner style process dialog for 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

In my code below, I want a spinner style process dialog for 5 seconds after the user clicks "Check For Root". Basically after the user hits the button, the process dialog will say "Please wait..." for 5 seconds and then display the results.
How do I do that ? Please help!

```
Button Root = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Root);
    Root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations!");
                    builder.setMessage("You Have Root Access!");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }

            else  {
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setTitle("Oops!");
                    builder.setMessage("No Root Access!");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();  
            }
        }
```

Comment: you mean the dialog change the text("Please wait..." to result text) after 5s?

Comment: No! The progress dialog would end after 5 seconds and then a dialog box with results would appear. I just need help with the the progress dialog part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private Button Root;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...........

    Root = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Root);
    Root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait...", true);

            mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 5000);
        }
    });

    ...........

}


private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        showDialog();
    }
};

private void showDialog() {

    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle("Congratulations!");
        builder.setMessage("You Have Root Access!");

        builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle("Oops!");
        builder.setMessage("No Root Access!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();  
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting some errors over mTimeHandler and mTimeExecutor

Comment: Illegal modifier for parameter mTimerHandler; only final is permitted

Comment: Illegal modifier for parameter mProgressDialog; only final is permitted

Comment: Declare `mProgressDialog`, `mTimerHandler` before `onCreate()` method and `mTimeExecutor` thread outside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String, boolean)

Comment: You sure that we need to declare mTimeExecutor outside OnCreate() ??

Comment: Now, see the `show()` method and replace the previous one with this....I will suggest you to study more about Java.

Comment: Thanks! No problems with show(), now. Stuck with mTimeExecutor; mTimerExecutor cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: clean your project then see...tell me.

Comment: Rectified. Cleaned. Still, mTimerExecutor cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: I said you to put the `mTimerExecutor` outside the `onCreate()` method but you put it inside the `onCreate()` method as I have seen in your last question where you give an screen shot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49241/discussion-between-hamid-shatu-and-the-maverick)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

            setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);

            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BrandList.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            Thread thread = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(5000); // the time in millis.
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {


                    } finally {
                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                        //do your stuff.

                    }

                }
            };


            thread.start(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery loader for this purpose. Find Jquery loader JS and Jquery CSS and include them in you application.

write this code on page load

```
$.loader({
className:"blue-with-image-2",
content:''
});
write this after the query or process is completed:


$.loader('close');
```

This closes the loader after the process is done. You can place some text instead of loader also. Hope this helps